# set programatically default text in DropDownListControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

How can I set programatically default text in DropDownListControl?Do I must define ValueField with default text?

Comment: dropDownList.SelectedValue = "default"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programatically set the default text (i.e. the default selected item) in a number of ways:

```
1) dd.SelectedIndex = 0; // by using known index of a DropDownItem, where 0 is your index

2) dd.Items[0].Selected = true; // by setting Selected = true; on an item at a known index, where 0 is your index

3) dd.SelectedIndex = dd.Items.IndexOf(dd.Items.FindByText("my item")); // by using known Text value of a DropDownItem, where "my item" is the known text
```

Assuming your `DropDownList` is named `dd`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
myDdl.Items.Insert(0, "Default text");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListItem item =new ListItem();
item.Text = "Select . . .";
item.Value = "Select";
item.Selected = true;

dropdownlist1.Items.Add(item);
```